# Control footnotes placement in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

When I export to LaTeX -> PDF the footnote description is placed on the same page the reference appears.  Instead, I'd like all the descriptions to appear in the end of the article.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use the LaTeX-package called endnotes from your org document.

Export the following org document to see it in action:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{endnotes}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}

* Header

This is a footnote [fn:f].

* An other header

With the endnotes CTAN package endnotes can be printed to the end of
the document [fn:e].

\clearpage

The place for endnotes need to be indicated with the \LaTeX command:

\theendnotes

* Footnotes

[fn:f] Footnotes are usually at the end of the page.

[fn:e] Endnotes are all collected to the end of the document.
```